# 3rd level on the fly binding models in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to bind 2 level of models to mine (user hasmany comments, comments hasmany tags) on the fly. I tried this but it won't work. Also found nothing that would work here or via google.

```
$this->User->bindModel(array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'Comment' => array(
                'classname' => 'Comment',
                'hasMany' => array(
                    'Tag' => array(
                        'classname' => 'Tag'
                    )
                )
            ) 
        ) 
    ));
```

Any other ideas?

I'm using Cakephp 2.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->User->bindModel(array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'Comment' => array(
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('User.id = Comment.user_id')
            ))));
```

and after this:

```
$this->User->Comment->bindModel(...)
```

But use Containable Behaviors, you will really develop faster, and can bind Tag with your Comment Model and juste use "contain"  see : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: Works like a charm with $this->User->recursive = 2;! Thanks! I know the containable behaviour but for that I would have to bind my data permanently which is exactly what I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$this->User->bindModel(array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'Comment' => array(
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('User.id = Comment.user_id')
            ),
            'Tag' => array(
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('Comment.id = Tag.comment_id')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Notice that we are setting foreign key to false , And forcing conditions for JOIN.

**UPDATE**

@MrSmith Hi Use proper hasMany association in Models.In User model use hasMany Comment .In comment model use hasMany Tag. You dont need to have On the fly relationship here if its not working by custom Solution.And wherever you DONT need this relationship,ON THE FLY use unbind model .Getting? Be smart.

Comment: This is not working for me. Cakephp does not join the User table in the resulting SQL-Statement:
    "SELECT `Comment`.`id` FROM `db`.`comments` AS `Comment` WHERE `User`.`id` = `Comment`.`user_id`"

Comment: @MrSmith Hi Use proper hasMany association in Models.In User model use hasMany Comment .In comment model use hasMany Tag. You dont need to have On the fly relationship here if its not working by custom Solution.And wherever you DONT need this relationship,ON THE FLY use unbind model .Getting? Be smart.

Comment: Smart? It would be smart if you need the data more often bound than unbound. Otherwise you would always have to check if you unbound it. That wouldn't be smart. And since I only need this binding once....